# Count maximum games in a 8 teams tournament such that there always exists 3 teams among which no game has been held

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-optimization, extremal-graph-theory

8 teams play a tournament in which every team plays every other team exactly once. As the tournament goes, $k$ games have been held and ${8\choose 2}-k=28-k$ games are waiting. In all the cases that $k$ games are conducted, there always exists 3 teams among which no game has been held. What is the maximum value of $k$?

My try:

I want to solve this issue using probability. Namely, I want to get the probability $p$ that there exists 3 teams among which no game has been conducted, and let $p=1$ to get the range of $k$ that satisfying the condition. And since this is a discrete problem, I should retrieve the maximum value of $k$.

Specifically, there are $C_8^3=56$ combinations of 3 teams. If we number them from $1$ to $56$, and use $A_i, i=1,2,...,56$ to denote the event that there isn't any game among these 3 teams, we can get $p=P(A_1\cup A_2\cup...A_{56})$. Thus, the problem is changed to solve $P(A_1\cup A_2\cup...A_{56})$. Besides, I solve $P(A_i)=\frac{28-k}{28}\frac{27-k}{27}\frac{26-k}{26}$.

I have tried two ideas. The first is to use inverse event: $P(\cup_{i=1}^{56}A_i)=1-P(\cap_{i=1}^{56}\bar{A_i})$. However, $\bar{A_i}$ are not independent to each other. It is complex to compute the conditional probability here.

Thus, I try to solve it directly. Namely, $P(\cup_{i=1}^{56}A_i)=\sum\limits_{l=1}^{56}(-1)^{l+1}\sum\limits_{1<=i_1<...<i_l<=56}P(A_{i_1}...A_{i_l})$. And for each $l$, I can list all the possible number of teams involved and how many games are held in this case, but, in the same way, it is too complex.

I think there might be an elegant way to solve this issue. Methods beyond probability are welcome. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Well, what I mean is that in all cases that $k$ games are held there always exists 3 teams among which no game has been held. Thus, the probability that such 3 teams exist should be $1$, namely $p=1$.

Comment: OK then I should have written: "If I have understood correctly, I suspect you want the largest $k$ such that $p=1$. Getting $p>0$ is a much weaker condition and occurs when $k \le {8 \choose 2}-{3 \choose2} = 25$"

Comment: Right, thank you. I have modified my statement.

Comment: Did you instead mean *at most* once?  If every team plays every other team *exactly* once, then there are exactly $k=\binom{8}{2}=28$ games.

Comment: Oh, right. I understand your worries. What I means here is a middle state. The tournament has not finished when $k$ games have been held.

Comment: So you want to find a largest (with respect to number of edges) subgraph $H$ of $K_8$ so that the complement $K_8 \setminus H$ contains a $K_3$?

Comment: Yeah, in some way. I think this statement is more clear in graph theory: find maximum $k$, s.t. for every subgraph $H=<V,E>, |E|\leq k$ of $K_8$, the complement $K_8 \setminus H$ contains a $K_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalently, you want to find the smallest $k+1$ so that there exists a subgraph $H$ of $K_8$ with $k$ edges that contains at least one edge from every $K_3$.  This is a *set covering* problem, and the minimum turns out to be $k+1=13$.  One such optimal subgraph with $12$ edges is $K_4 \cup K_4$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know this kind of problem definitely has a name, but I don't know *set covering* until now. This is exactly what I am looking for. I have some thoughts about solve this question by counting the minimum number of edges that contains at least one edge from every $K_3$. But, the counting is really complex with the divide-and-conquer strategy, so I resort to probability.